# Trouble Rendering 2 Object separately in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I have taken code for two projects. One being the code for creating a cube and another is the code for creating a pyramid. I am now trying to render both of the objects in OpenGL which I have done the problem is the objects are attached to one another. I have added some code heading towards rendering them separately, however I am now stuck where my cube is only showing 3 of the triangles used to create it and the whole pyramid shows. Yet the objects are still attached to one another. Any help or guidance?

[image]

```
#include <iostream>         // cout, cerr
#include <cstdlib>          // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <GL/glew.h>        // GLEW library
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>     // GLFW library

// GLM Math Header inclusions
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std; // Standard namespace
using glm::vec3;
using glm::mat4;
/*Shader program Macro*/
#ifndef GLSL
#define GLSL(Version, Source) "#version " #Version " core \n" #Source
#endif

// Unnamed namespace
namespace
{
    const char* const WINDOW_TITLE = "3D Scene Troubleshooting"; // Macro for window title

    // Variables for window width and height
    const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
    const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

    // Stores the GL data relative to a given mesh
    struct GLMesh
    {
        GLuint vao;  // Handle for the vertex array object 1
        GLuint vao2; // Handle for the vertex array object 2
        GLuint vbos[2];     // Handles for the vertex buffer objects 1
        GLuint vbos2[2];    // Handles for the vertex buffer objects 2
        GLuint cubeIndices;    // Number of cube indices of the mesh
        GLuint pyramidIndices; // Number of pyramid indices of the mesh
    };

    // Main GLFW window
    GLFWwindow* gWindow = nullptr;
    // Triangle mesh data
    GLMesh gMesh;
    // Shader program
    GLuint gProgramId;
}

/* User-defined Function prototypes to:
 * initialize the program, set the window size,
 * redraw graphics on the window when resized,
 * and render graphics on the screen
 */
bool UInitialize(int, char* [], GLFWwindow** window);
void UResizeWindow(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void UProcessInput(GLFWwindow* window);
void UCreateMesh(GLMesh& mesh);
void UDestroyMesh(GLMesh& mesh);
void URender();
bool UCreateShaderProgram(const char* vtxShaderSource, const char* fragShaderSource, GLuint& programId);
void UDestroyShaderProgram(GLuint programId);


/* Vertex Shader Source Code*/
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = GLSL(440,
    layout(location = 0) in vec3 position; // Vertex data from Vertex Attrib Pointer 0
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;  // Color data from Vertex Attrib Pointer 1

out vec4 vertexColor; // variable to transfer color data to the fragment shader

//Global variables for the  transform matrices
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f); // transforms vertices to clip coordinates
    vertexColor = color; // references incoming color data
}
);


/* Fragment Shader Source Code*/
const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = GLSL(440,
    in vec4 vertexColor; // Variable to hold incoming color data from vertex shader

out vec4 fragmentColor;

void main()
{
    fragmentColor = vec4(vertexColor);
}
);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (!UInitialize(argc, argv, &gWindow))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Create the mesh
    UCreateMesh(gMesh); // Calls the function to create the Vertex Buffer Object

    // Create the shader program
    if (!UCreateShaderProgram(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource, gProgramId))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Sets the background color of the window to black (it will be implicitely used by glClear)
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gWindow))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        UProcessInput(gWindow);

        // Render this frame
        URender();

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // Release mesh data
    UDestroyMesh(gMesh);

    // Release shader program
    UDestroyShaderProgram(gProgramId);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // Terminates the program successfully
}


// Initialize GLFW, GLEW, and create a window
bool UInitialize(int argc, char* argv[], GLFWwindow** window)
{
    // GLFW: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // GLFW: window creation
    // ---------------------
    * window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "3D Scene TroubleShooting", NULL, NULL);
    if (*window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(*window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(*window, UResizeWindow);

    // GLEW: initialize
    // ----------------
    // Note: if using GLEW version 1.13 or earlier
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum GlewInitResult = glewInit();

    if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult)
    {
        std::cerr << glewGetErrorString(GlewInitResult) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Displays GPU OpenGL version
    cout << "INFO: OpenGL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;

    return true;
}


// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
void UProcessInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}


// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function 
executes
void UResizeWindow(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}


// Functioned called to render a frame
void URender()
{
    // Enable z-depth
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Clear the frame and z buffers
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // 1. Scales the object by 2
    glm::mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f));
    // 2. Rotates shape by 15 degrees in the x axis
    glm::mat4 rotation = glm::rotate(45.0f, glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    // 3. Place object at the origin
    glm::mat4 translation = glm::translate(glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.3f, -0.1f));
    // Model matrix: transformations are applied right-to-left order
    glm::mat4 model = translation * rotation * scale;

    // Transforms the camera: move the camera back (z axis)
    glm::mat4 view = glm::translate(glm::vec3(-2.6f, 2.9f, -5.0f));

    // Creates a orthographic projection
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(-5.0f, 5.0f, -5.0f, 5.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    // Set the shader to be used
    glUseProgram(gProgramId);

    // Retrieves and passes transform matrices to the Shader program
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(gProgramId, "model");
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(gProgramId, "view");
    GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(gProgramId, "projection");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    // Activate the VBOs contained within the mesh's VAO
    glBindVertexArray(gMesh.vao);
    glBindVertexArray(gMesh.vao2);

    // Draws the CUBE
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, gMesh.cubeIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL); // Draws the triangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 24);

    // Draws the PYRAMID
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, gMesh.pyramidIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL); // Draws the triangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 54);

    // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
    glfwSwapBuffers(gWindow);    // Flips the the back buffer with the front buffer every frame.
}

void UCylinder(GLUquadric* qobj, GLdouble baseRadius, GLdouble topRadius, GLdouble height, GLint slices, GLint stacks)
{
    GLUquadricObj* quadratic;
    quadratic = gluNewQuadric();
    gluCylinder(quadratic, 0.3f, 0.3f, 3.0f, 32, 32);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, gMesh.cubeIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
}

// Implements the UCreateMesh function
void UCreateMesh(GLMesh& mesh)
{
    // Position and Color data
    GLfloat verts[] = {
        // Vertex Positions    // Colors (r,g,b,a)
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Top Right Vertex 0 (effects top right and bottom right top sides of cube)
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom Right corner Vertex 1 
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom center of cube Vertex 2 (effects bottom left and bottomr right sides of cube)
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Center of cube Vertex 3 (effects top, bottom left and bottom right sides of cube)

         0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //  Bottomside left of cube Vertex 4 (doesn't effect cube color at all with current orientation)
         0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //  Top center of cube Vertex 5
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //  Top left corner cube Vertex 6 (effects both top and bottom left sides of cube)
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  //  Bottom left of cube Vertex 7

        // Vertex Positions    // Colors (r,g,b,a)
     -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 8
       0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 9
       0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 10

     -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 11
      0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 12
      0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 13

      -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 14
      -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 15
       0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 16

      0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 17
      0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 18
      0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 19

      0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 20
      0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 21
      0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 22

      -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 23
       0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 24
       0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Vertex 25
    };

    // Index data to share position data
    GLushort cubeIndices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,  // Triangle 1
        1, 2, 3,   // Triangle 2
        0, 1, 4,  // Triangle 3
        0, 4, 5,  // Triangle 4
        0, 5, 6, // Triangle 5
        0, 3, 6,  // Triangle 6
        4, 5, 6, // Triangle 7
        4, 6, 7, // Triangle 8
        2, 3, 6, // Triangle 9
        2, 6, 7, // Triangle 10
        1, 4, 7, // Triangle 11
        1, 2, 7, // Triangle 12
    };
    GLushort pyramidIndices[] = {
        8, 9, 10, // Triangle 1
        11, 12, 13, // Triangle 2
        14, 15, 16, // Triangle 3
        17, 18, 19, // Triangle 4
        20, 21, 22, // Triangle 5
        23, 24, 25 // Triangle 6
    };

    const GLuint floatsPerVertex = 3;
    const GLuint floatsPerColor = 4;

    // For CUBE
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mesh.vao); // we can also generate multiple VAOs or buffers at the same time
    glBindVertexArray(mesh.vao);

    // For PYRAMID
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mesh.vao2);
    glBindVertexArray(mesh.vao2);

    // Create 2 buffers: first one for the vertex data; second one for the indices for the CUBE
    glGenBuffers(2, mesh.vbos);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbos[0]); // Activates the buffer for CUBE
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Sends vertex or coordinate data to the GPU for CUBE

    // Create 2 buffers: first one for the vertex data; second one for the indices for the PYRAMID
    glGenBuffers(2, mesh.vbos2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbos2[0]); // Activates the buffer for PYRAMID
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Sends vertex or coordinate data to the GPU for PYRAMID
    // For CUBE
    mesh.cubeIndices = sizeof(cubeIndices) / sizeof(cubeIndices[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbos[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeIndices), cubeIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // For PYRAMID
    mesh.pyramidIndices = sizeof(pyramidIndices) / sizeof(pyramidIndices[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbos2[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidIndices), pyramidIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

    // Strides between vertex coordinates is 6 (x, y, z, r, g, b, a). A tightly packed stride is 0.
    GLint stride = sizeof(float) * (floatsPerVertex + floatsPerColor);// The number of floats before each

    // Create Vertex Attribute Pointers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, floatsPerVertex, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, floatsPerColor, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (char*)(sizeof(float) * floatsPerVertex));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
}


void UDestroyMesh(GLMesh& mesh)
{
    // For CUBE
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &mesh.vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(2, mesh.vbos);

    // For PYRAMID
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &mesh.vao2);
    glDeleteBuffers(2, mesh.vbos2);
}


// Implements the UCreateShaders function
bool UCreateShaderProgram(const char* vtxShaderSource, const char* fragShaderSource, GLuint& programId)
{
    // Compilation and linkage error reporting
    int success = 0;
    char infoLog[512];

    // Create a Shader program object.
    programId = glCreateProgram();

    // Create the vertex and fragment shader objects
    GLuint vertexShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Retrive the shader source
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderId, 1, &vtxShaderSource, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderId, 1, &fragShaderSource, NULL);

    // Compile the vertex shader, and print compilation errors (if any)
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderId); // compile the vertex shader
    // check for shader compile errors
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderId, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;

        return false;
    }

    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderId); // compile the fragment shader
    // check for shader compile errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderId, sizeof(infoLog), NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;

        return false;
    }

    // Attached compiled shaders to the shader program
    glAttachShader(programId, vertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(programId, fragmentShaderId);

    glLinkProgram(programId);   // links the shader program
    // check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programId, sizeof(infoLog), NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;

        return false;
    }

    glUseProgram(programId);    // Uses the shader program

    return true;
}


void UDestroyShaderProgram(GLuint programId)
{
    glDeleteProgram(programId);
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `glDrawElements` and  `glDrawArrays`?

Comment: I am not sure why I called both, but if I remove glDrawElements than my cube disappears and if I remove glDrawArrays part of my pyramid disappears

Comment: What's up with those back-to-back `glBindVertexArray()` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification). You cannot specify 2 vertex array objects at the same time. You have to do this in a row.
The Vertex Array Binding is a global state. Only one VAO can be bound at a time.
When calling OpenGL instructions like `glVertexAttribPointer`, `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,`...)`, the state of the currently bound Vertex Array Object is changed. Note that different VAOs can use the same data buffers.

```cpp
void UCreateMesh(GLMesh& mesh)
{
    // [...]

    glGenBuffers(1, mesh.vbos);
    glGenBuffers(2, mesh.vbos2);

    // 1 Vertex Buffer for both objects
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbos[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Strides between vertex coordinates is 6 (x, y, z, r, g, b, a). A tightly packed stride is 0.
    GLint stride = sizeof(float) * (floatsPerVertex + floatsPerColor);// The number of floats before each

    // CUBE

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mesh.vao); // we can also generate multiple VAOs or buffers at the same time
    glBindVertexArray(mesh.vao);

    // Create Vertex Attribute Pointers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, floatsPerVertex, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, floatsPerColor, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (char*)(sizeof(float) * floatsPerVertex));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    mesh.cubeIndices = sizeof(cubeIndices) / sizeof(cubeIndices[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbos[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeIndices), cubeIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // PYRAMID

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mesh.vao2);
    glBindVertexArray(mesh.vao2);

    // Create Vertex Attribute Pointers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, floatsPerVertex, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, floatsPerColor, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (char*)(sizeof(float) * floatsPerVertex));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    mesh.pyramidIndices = sizeof(pyramidIndices) / sizeof(pyramidIndices[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbos2[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidIndices), pyramidIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 
}
```

Finally you can draw the meshes one after the other. The draw call uses the data from the currently bound Vertex Array Object. As already mentioned, only one VAO can be bound at a time:

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(gMesh.vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, gMesh.cubeIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);

glBindVertexArray(gMesh.vao2);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, gMesh.pyramidIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
```